# Jquery Mobile loading page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am new to Jquery mobile and Jquery. I am trying to develop a mobile application. The thing is that I have  a result page which displays the result of products, clicking on any product will take you to a description page about that product. I have navbar in the middle of the page with 5 buttons , each links to a different page. I want to load respective pages in the div block below the navbar. I have used jquery document.ready function which works fine but when I click on a particular product on a result page it takes me to the description page but the dynamic loading happens only after I reload that description page. Any suggestion as to improve or better methodology ?

Result page.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <a href="#mypanel" data-role="button" data-icon="grid">Menu</a> <!--Top right MENU button -->
    <h1> Results </h1>
    </div> <!-- end of the header -->


    <div data-role="content">    <!-- Start of the content -->
    <form method="post">
    <ul data-role="listview">
    <li>
    <a href="wine.php?wid=1">
    <img src="images/images.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="padding:10px;"   />
    <h1> Wine 1</h1>
    <p style="font-style:italic"> This is wine 1 </p>
    <h3> 1962</h3>
   </a>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="wine.php?wid=2" data-transition="slide"><img src="images/images (1).jpg" height="100" width="100"   style="padding:10px;"/><h1> Wine 2</h1>
    <p> This is wine 2 </p>
    <h3> 1962</h3>
    </a>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="wine.php?wid=3"><img src="images/images.jpg" height="100" width="100"  style="padding:10px;" /><h1> Wine 3</h1>
    <p> This is wine 3 </p>
    <h3> 1962</h3>
    </a>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="wine.php?wid=4"><img src="images/images.jpg" height="100" width="100"  style="padding:10px;" /><h1> Wine 4</h1>
    <p> This is wine 4 </p>
    <h3> 1962</h3>
    </a>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="wine.php?wid=4"><img src="images/images (1).jpg" height="100" width="100"  style="padding:10px;" /><h1> Wine 5</h1>
    <p> This is wine 5 </p>
    <h3> 1962</h3>
    </a>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </div>
```

Description page:

```
<body> 
<div id="result" data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
<a href="#mypanel" data-role="button" data-icon="grid">Menu</a> <!--Top right MENU button -->
<h1> Wine Description </h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" id="swipe">
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
    echo '<h1>'.$row->wine_name.'</h1>';
    echo '<p>'.$row->wine_id.'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$row->wine_desc.'</p>';
    echo '<p><i>'.$row->year.'</i></p>';

}
?>
</div>
<div data-role="navbar" style="background-color:#000; color:#FFDFFF; height:50px; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px">
<ul id="menu">
<li><a id="description"> Description</a></li>
<li><a id="producer" > Producer</a> </li>
<li><a id="journal">Journal </a></li>
<li><a id="rating"> Ratings </a></li>
<li><a id="mediaRating"> Media Ratings </a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="content"></div>
```

.js file :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('#content').load('description.php');
    $('ul#menu li a').click(function(e){
    //  alert('U have reached the click function')
    var page = $(this).attr('id');  
 // alert("Hello World "+page);
     $('#content').load(page+'.php');

    });

});
```

Assume all the dependencies are loaded. 
I am using Jquery Mobile 1.3.1 , Jquery 1.10

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem and if I am correct you will need to change page handling.
When jQuery Mobile handles pages it uses **AJAX** to load them into the DOM. Only first page is fully loaded, every other page will be stripped from its **HEAD** content and only **`data-role="page"`** div will be loaded.

This is why your javascript is working only after page reload. To find more about this problem take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)**. You will find several working solutions there with working examples.

Comment: There is a lot of good information on the subject right on Stack Overflow...